# Can Michael, Trevor and Franklin take on the military together?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to steal some cool toys from the Zancudo military base, however the amount of soldiers is too high to take on them easily in one person. Besides, the idea of them stealing the equipment feels really cool.

Is it possible to somehow get them all to the fortress and control them? Because normally, wanted stars prevent me from switching characters.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to another answer of mine [How to escape Fort Zancudo without getting wasted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354561/how-do-i-escape-fort-zancudo-without-getting-wasted-as-franklin/355439#355439) you're going to have a very difficult time raiding the base. The core issue is that while you can enter the base via vehicle you cannot exit by car (or tank). The gates do not open from the inside.

You'll need to exit the fort via aircraft and there are only three that spawn with enough seats for the Michael, Franklin and Trevor: The Buzzard, the Annihilator and the Cargobob. This is a dangerous task because these aircraft don't have a guarantee of spawning in the first place unlike the P-996 Lazor jet plane. Likewise, these vehicles are exposed on the airfield and take time to spool up before taking flight.

Of the three the buzzard attack helicopter is your safest bet to escape: it has the shortest idling period and strongest armaments. After entering the aircraft you must wait around five seconds for the rotors to spin enough to generate lift. During this time you will be susceptible to incoming small arms fire, tank shells and homing rockets.

The last obstacle in the plan is the fact that you will be unable to switch characters during this raid. Despite all three characters being together you still cannot switch characters while you are wanted (story missions are exceptions). That means that if you die while playing as Trevor you will be unable to switch to Franklin.

In conclusion, this is a very risky operation and there is not much in terms of rewards. The minigun in the air traffic control tower is better than nothing, but even acquiring that is exceedingly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

To add to PausePause's answer, the only way to reunite all three characters outside of a mission (as far as I know) is to control one character and set up a hangout with the other two, which can be done by calling them and selecting the "Hangout" option.

But I can't see why would you want to do that, besides the roleplay factor. NPCs aren't really that helpful, and, even if they were, it's definitely doable to invade it by yourself if you plan ahead.

Comment: You can encounter the other protagonists in the open world with a little work. If two characters are within reasonable distance you can play as each other (swapping characters frequently) to guide them to an encounter, from there you can start hanging out. It does not exclusively need to be set up from your phone.

Comment: True. Although it's rare to find one of them wandering the world without your input (as in putting them somewhere and going to that location you put them with another character), let alone both of them.